# Does Flink's windowing operation process elements at the end of window or does it do a rolling processing?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am having some trouble understanding the way windowing is implemented internally in Flink and could not find any article which explain this in depth. In my mind, there are two ways this can be done. Consider a simple window wordcount code as below

```
env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
    .flatMap(new Splitter())
    .groupBy(0)
    .window(Time.of(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).sum(1)
```

Method 1: Store all events for 500 seconds and at the end of the window, process all of them by applying the sum operation on the stored events.

Method 2: We use a counter to store a rolling sum for every window. As each event in a window comes, we do not store the individual events but keep adding 1 to previously stored counter and output the result at the end of the window.

Could someone kindly help to understand which of the above methods (or maybe a different approach) is used by Flink in reality. The reason is, there are pros and cons to both approach and is important to understand in order configure the resources for the cluster correctly.
eg: The Method 1 seems very close to batch processing and might potentially have issues related to spike in processing at every 500 sec interval while sitting idle otherwise etc while Method2 would need to maintain a common counter between all task managers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum` is a reducing function as mentioned here(https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#reducefunction). Internally, Flink will apply reduce function to each input element, and simply save the reduced result in `ReduceState`.

For other windows functions, like `windows.apply(WindowFunction)`. There is no aggregation so all input elements will be saved in the `ListState`.

This document(https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#window-functions) about windows stream mentions about how the internal elements are handled in Flink.